# git clone, "checking out files" phase skipped

Tags: git, git-clone, git-checkout

```
ubuntu@site3-user03:/projects$ git clone git://git.alsa-project.org/alsa-driver.git
```

was carried out. It resulted in following output

```
Cloning into 'alsa-driver'...
remote: Counting objects: 208801, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (41538/41538), done.
remote: Total 208801 (delta 162528), reused 206283 (delta 160012)
Receiving objects: 100% (208801/208801), 37.00 MiB | 1.53 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (162528/162528), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
ubuntu@site3-user03:/projects$
```

However, for some unknown reason the clone process did not include the stage
*Checking out files: 100% (xyz/zyx), done.*
Usually the clone process includes checkout to working space. In end-effect my private fork has empty working space and myself has to decide where to branch out which might not be straightforward.

```
ubuntu@site3-user03:/projects/alsa-driver$ git ls-remote origin
a1c6fbc1a65d8a755425d0b56077868148512891    HEAD
1721fb542b00f1c7aebc923732068f403b6062ad    refs/heads/build
a1c6fbc1a65d8a755425d0b56077868148512891    refs/heads/master
71b3b2b41dfbdeda78e2e7b62fe2afa8b451fb6e    refs/heads/mirror
b044dfe04f636d87fd391b575ba41e495e68e973    refs/heads/release
6386d9e39e6f364698648f4e4741897f83b00121    refs/tags/build/v1.0.1
234b00ebe6e1513c3ce8cdd83999c255bd5516eb    refs/tags/build/v1.0.10
f888eb06d4c7af89faa2f9dda189d488312ecb07    refs/tags/build/v1.0.10rc1
e4c4d1037521f536b79f8d145979ec869db353f9    refs/tags/build/v1.0.10rc2
....
many more tags
```

My expectation is the clone carries out the check-out based on remote's HEAD which points to certain commit on remote.
**What is the possible reason of the check-out stage had been skipped?**
During the clone process was in progress I created small readme file in the working space. However that file stays untracked up to this moment. There is no plan to track that file.
**Can this file creation have disturbed clone process so it could not include check-out stage?**

```
ubuntu@site3-user03:/projects$ git clone git@git.alsa-project.org:alsa-driver.git alsa-driver  
Cloning into 'alsa-driver'...  
The authenticity of host 'git.alsa-project.org (77.48.224.243)' can't be established.  
RSA key fingerprint is f1:0e:a7:1f:bc:1b:9f:71:00:85:c9:4a:8a:d9:d6:33.  
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? no   
Host key verification failed.  
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.  

Please make sure you have the correct access rights  
and the repository exists.  
ubuntu@site3-user03:/projects$
```

So, I aborted it because am used to have straightforward clone process, furthermore not the slightest idea about all resulting effects on confirming to continue on unauthenticated host.

```
git help clone
```

and the examples made there use among others following URL format

```
 The following syntaxes may be used with them:
   ·   git://host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/
   ·   http[s]://host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/
   ...
 git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/.../linux.git my-linux
 git clone --reference /git/linux.git \
                   git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/.../linux.git \
                   my-linux
·   Create a bare repository to publish your changes to the public:
    git clone --bare -l /home/proj/.git /pub/scm/proj.git
```

As for used setup following applies as well:

```
ubuntu@site3-user03:/$ sudo find / -type f -name known_hosts
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
ubuntu@site3-user03:/$
```

One time in the past I have had similar effect with other clone. That time it was clone of Linux kernel public repo for MSM SoC. However, that time the clone process generated also some message of the kind "unable to clone because no ??? found on remote". Forgotten what ??? read. So in the end-effect I had also to do check-out manually subsequently to clone process. However, such warning did not come in this case, forking alsa-driver public repo.

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen using the URL format you use to clone a repository, since the standard should be : `git://git.alsa-project.org:alsa-driver.git`, with the format you used you are cloning the repository in bare mode, that is like specifying the `--bare` command line option, that basically perform :

> Make a bare Git repository. That is, instead of creating `<directory>` and placing the administrative files in `<directory>/.git`,
>   make the `<directory>` itself the `$GIT_DIR`. This obviously implies the
>   `-n` because there is nowhere to check out the working tree. Also the branch heads at the remote are copied directly to corresponding local
>   branch heads, without mapping them to `refs/remotes/origin/`. When this
>   option is used, neither remote-tracking branches nor the related
>   configuration variables are created.

If you take a look at the [documentation of the project](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/GIT_Server) that you are trying to clone you'll notice that to clone that specific project you have to :

```
git clone git@git.alsa-project.org:alsa-driver.git alsa-driver
cd alsa-driver
git branch build remotes/origin/build
git branch mirror remotes/origin/mirror
git branch release remotes/origin/release
```

Comment: ubuntu@site3-user03:/projects$ git clone git@git.alsa-project.org:alsa-driver.git alsa-driver  
Cloning into 'alsa-driver'...  
The authenticity of host 'git.alsa-project.org (77.48.224.243)' can't be established.  
RSA key fingerprint is f1:0e:a7:1f:bc:1b:9f:71:00:85:c9:4a:8a:d9:d6:33.  
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? no   
Host key verification failed.  
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.  

Please make sure you have the correct access rights  
and the repository exists.  
ubuntu@site3-user03:/projects$

Comment: The message is clear, you have a ssh key mismatch, delete the key in known_hosts file and try again ...

Comment: @Na13-c try deleting the known_hosts under your .ssh directory in your home directory .

Comment: I expect that find command invoked as shown above (merged to the Q) finds known_hosts anywhere the file is placed. However, the search does not result in any matches.

Comment: Again, you should have a known_hosts file somewhere, anyway this issue is different than the originally posted one, so you should post on super user this new issue you have ... I've answered your question and you ended up asking another question ... Open another post .

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help! "... you are cloning the repository in bare mode, that is like specifying the --bare ...". I didn't find such hint neither in git help clone, nor git help fetch, nor the Pro Git book. Is this your Git knowledge? Or Git document stating this known as well? git help clone does not point out any specifics regarding format git://host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/   .   However, I notice that the git://host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/ form is not the same what you are pointing out in your A.  As the form pointed by you is rather git://host.xz:/path/to/repo.git/  .

Comment: "..the format you used you are cloning the repository in bare mode.." - what is the deciding element if cloning in bare or normal mode? The "/alsa-dri.." instead of ":alsa-dri.."? "git://..." shouldn't be as it determines just the used data transfer protocol. I ask this question because my next trial "git clone http://git.linuxfoundation.org/ltsi-kernel.git" generates expected results - working space produced - and of same syntax as my cloning of alsa-driver repo.

Comment: As of this minute I see following reason of describe phenomenon: used remote names its master in the following form "some-string/master". The checkout however needs origin/master so it fails in this case. * I was not able to find statements in git documents confirming aleroot's friendly elaborations. *